# Graphical tool to generate JavaScript/HTML5 tweening?

Tags: javascript, ide

Is there a tool that writes tweening in javascript with just a few clicks? (similar to what Adobe tools used to do for Flash, but I've heard that Flash is dead)

While there are a few JavaScript tweening libraries around, I'm wondering if someone has already written a tool that can take points someone selected, and make tweens for them, and assemble several of them together, or not. I'm considering writing an open source (free) project to do this.

***Definition of tweening***: A motion tween is an animation that is created by specifying different values for an object property in different frames. Flash Pro calculates the values for that property in between those two frames. The term tween comes from the words “in between”. For instance, a small red circle starts from the left and becomes a big blue circle while moving to the right.

Comment: Can the hold on this now be lifted?

Comment: So, you don't care about what tweening library will be used, but you want it to have a tool that allows you to define the tweenings with the mouse? Did I understand your request correctly?

Comment: I was thinking about a natural javascript tweening technology, then replace the "writer" setup for if someone wanted it in other languages also.

Comment: Also known as interpolation (typically linear interpolation).  What kind of data do you want to tween/interpolate?  SVG is often a good bet.